# Conventional notation for this matrix operation

Tags: matrices, notation, adjacency-matrix

Given some binary adjacency matrix $A$ and index $n$, define matrix $B$ such that $$B_{ij} = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $(A^n)_{ij} \geq 1$} \\ 0 & \text{if $(A^n)_{ij} < 1$} \end{cases}$$

e.g. $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, n=2, \qquad \text{then} \qquad B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Is there an established notation instead of using $f(A^n) = B$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Those things are $(A^n)_{ij}$, not $(A_{ij})^n$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo what alternative would you use? - $(A^n)_{ij}$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo. It is binary, I shall add that into the question.

Comment: So, essentially, $B$ gives the sparsity pattern of $A^n$, right?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yes.

Comment: This would be the sparsity pattern of $A^n-E$, where $E$ is the matrix of all $1$-s. I do not think there is an established name or notation. MATLAB uses [spy(A) command](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spy.html) for sparsity patterns but the output is a plot, not a matrix.

Comment: Since $A$ is a binary matrix, $A^n_{ij}\in\mathbb{Z}_+$. Therefore, $$B_{ij}=\begin{cases}
0&\text{ if }A^{n}_{ij}=0\\
1&\text{ otherwise .}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: @Conifold thank you, I think that is the closest to an answer I can get.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo For the simple reason that when I was working with these matrices I was thinking about them in terms of $x>1$ and $x<1$, I see that it has caused confusion regarding the elements of $A$ so I shall change that in future.
Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Conifold I don't understand how subtracting ones makes any sense whatsoever.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo It did not after an edit, which also left unclear what happens for entries between $0$ and $1$. I rolled it back.

Comment: @Conifold values between 0 and 1 don’t exist. Powers of an integer matrix only give integer elements.

Answer (score 0):

Using Boolean algebra, then $\rm{B} = \rm{A}^2$.

$$\rm{A}^2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = {\rm B}$$